# Как получить из NSString массив слов?

Tags: массивы, регулярные-выражения, ios, objective-c, строки

У меня есть большой текст. Я хочу получить массив слов разделенных знаками пунктуации (точка, запятая, двоеточие, точка с запятой, перенос строки) из этого текста. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: А есть еще такие слова `по-русски`.

Comment: Да, я не подумал. Спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение через `NSRegularExpression`. С таким паттерном остаются только слова (буквы, цифры, тире, нижнее подчеркивание)

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)"
                                                                  options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                    error:nil];
NSString* sourceString = @"This Web site includes information about Project Gutenberg-tm, including how to make donations to the Project Gutenberg Literary Archive Foundation, how to help produce our new eBooks, and how to subscribe to our email newsletter to hear about new eBooks.";
NSArray<NSTextCheckingResult *> *matches = [regex matchesInString:sourceString
                                                          options:NSMatchingWithoutAnchoringBounds
                                                            range:NSMakeRange(0, sourceString.length)];
NSMutableArray *words = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    [words addObject:[[sourceString substringWithRange:match.range] lowercaseString]];
}
```

На выходе получаем массив из слов в нижнем регистре.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать `NSCharacterSet` разделителей и по ним разбить строку на части:

```
NSString *text = @"..."; // ваш большой текст
NSCharacterSet *separatorsSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@".,:;\n"];
NSArray *words = [text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separatorsSet];
```